# How to display facebook wall feeds in drupal 7

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal-7

Following are the requirements:

1. The user will add his facebook user account and facebook page account(the access token and page/account id must be saved in database in this step).
2. These accounts will be listed in tabs.
3. When the user will click on a tab say "A", all the feeds/wall posts of "A" will be fetched and displayed.

Is there any drupal 7 module available? Or is thr any1 who has done this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this with some custom coding based on the drupal module Facebook Wall (https://drupal.org/project/facebook_wall).

This module came out a few months after your question. I am adding the answer now, because I found your question during a search.

With Facebook Wall, you need to enter an App ID/API Key, and the App Secret Key to the configuration page. To get an App ID/API Key, you need to create an app at http://developers.facebook.com.

Next, you enter the Facebook username (like first.last.number), click "save configuration".

Now, you need an access token for the site you want to pull. The configuration page has now given you an field for "Access Token Temporary", and a link to the Graph API Explorer. Open the link in a new tab, copy the access token shown on this page to the Drupal Facebook Wall Configuration Page "Access Token Temporary".

Click "Save" - now you are given the option "Get Long term Access token". Click on the button, and you are good for the next 60 days. Facebook doesn't give out access tokens anymore that are valid longer than 60 days.

In the tab "Wall Content", you can customize the pulling of your wall.

If you want to pull a public Facebook wall (like a fan page), you can still use this module. Enter your own API ID, and enter the username of the public page instead of your own username.